# How to load XML nodes and content into variables dynamically

Tags: javascript, xml, variables, nodes

I have a very long list of XML separated into sections. For each page it loads content from the XML based on a category node (list_node). For now I am grabbing the content by referencing the nodes directly, but I don't want to have to put in a line for every single node.

Is there a way to just read the XML, loads the nodes into an array, then set a new variable as the node name and loads in the contents? This is my current setup:

```
<media_item>
<title>temporary title</title>
<key>652843722</key>
<path>/states/CA</path>
<filename>climate-pollution-harmful.html</filename>
<link>http://a-url-goes-here.com</link>
<blank>yes</blank>
<author/>
<date>August&nbsp;15,&nbsp;2015</date>
</media_item>
```

(The XML has a lot more nodes then that, and different categories all specified by the "list_node" call earlier up in my code)

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://url-of/file.xml,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml){             
            $(xml).find(list_node).each(function(i){
                var title = $(this).find('title').text();
                var url = $(this).find('link').text();
                var date = $(this).find('date').text();
                var author = $(this).find('author').text();
                var org = $(this).find('org').text();
```

So instead of "var title = $(this).find('title').text();" for every single node, I'd just like it to do it automatically.

Comment: look into "xml2json" routines, like jsonml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the nodes are simply text nodes you can loop over `children()` and create an array of objects using the `tagName`'s as property names

```js
$.get('data.xml', function (xml) {

    var results = $(xml).find('media_item').map(function () {
        var row = {}
        $(this).children().each(function () {
            row[this.tagName] = $(this).text();
        });
        return row;
    }).get();

    console.log(results);

}, 'xml');
```

This can easily be adapted to include attributes as well.

The above code converts the xml shown to:

```js
[
 {
  "title": "temporary title",
  "key": "652843722",
  "path": "/states/CA",
  "filename": "climate-pollution-harmful.html",
  "link": "http://a-url-goes-here.com",
  "blank": "yes",
  "author": "",
  "date": "August 15, 2015"
 }
]
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/KwLZI0h4U5rD3mFMCDKo?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Great solution, that really helps me out! Thanks @charlietfl